# How can I return NSJsonSerialization

Tags: objective-c, react-native, nsjsonserialization, asyncstorage

First, I know nothing about Objective-C.

That said the follow code should be getting the data from **AsyncStorage**.

I've already did something like for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151030/how-to-read-asyncstorage-on-android-correctly/48165649#48165649) where the basic idea is get the data from AsyncStorage as Json Object.

What I need now, is use the `jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey` inside `callInviteReceived`

**jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey** *[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47389561/1958882)*

```
+(void)jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey:(NSString *)key completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary * _Nullable, NSError * _Nullable))completion
{
    RCTResponseSenderBlock rnCompletion = ^(NSArray *response) {

        NSString *jsonAsString;

        if (response.count > 1) {
            NSArray *response1 = response[1];
            if (response1.count > 0) {
                NSArray *response2 = response1[0];                
                if (response2.count > 1) {
                    jsonAsString = response2[1];
                }
            }
        }

        NSData *jsonAsData = [jsonAsString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSError *error;

        NSDictionary *json = [
            NSJSONSerialization
            JSONObjectWithData:jsonAsData
            options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
            error:&error
        ];

        completion(json, error);
    };

    RCTAsyncLocalStorage *storage = [RCTAsyncLocalStorage new];   

    dispatch_async(storage.methodQueue, ^{
        [storage performSelector:@selector(multiGet:callback:) withObject:@[key] withObject:rnCompletion];
    });
}
```

**callInviteReceived**

```
- (void)callInviteReceived:(TVOCallInvite *)callInvite {    
    NSJsonSerialization json = [self.jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey];
    // json.user.name
    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:@json.user.name withUUID:callInvite.uuid];
}
```

**These methods should be working something like**

```
-(NSJsonSerialization)jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey: {
    ...
    return json;
}

- (void)callInviteReceived {    
    ...

    NSJsonSerialization json = [self.jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey];

    // json.user.name
    [self reportIncomingCallFrom:json.user.name withUUID:callInvite.uuid];
}
```

So, is there anyone who could show me, how to code this?

---

[Using RCTAsyncLocalStorage + getAllKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280006/using-rctasynclocalstorage-getallkeys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would look something like this (You will need to supply the `storageKey` parameter):

```
- (void)callInviteReceived:(TVOCallInvite *)callInvite {    
    [self jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey:/*storageKey*/ completion:^(NSDictionary* data,NSError* error){
        if(data){
            NSString * name = [data valueForKeyPath@"user.name"];
            if(![name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
                [self reportIncomingCallFrom:name withUUID:callInvite.uuid];
            }
        }else{
            //handle error
            NSLog(@"JSON Parsing Error: %@",error.localizedDescription)
        }
   }
}
```

`NSJSONSerialization` is a utility class responsible for serializing and deserializing JSON. All of its methods are class methods, so it's pointless to pass it as a return value.

The output of deserialization is an `NSDictionary` which is a Map representation of the JSON. You can use this Map to extract values of `user.name`.

Comment: That worked! Tks a lot! By the way do you have any idea if there's an specific ```storageKey``` as root? Because every try I'm getting null. I also tried ```getAllKeys``` but I doesn't exists.

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that you used to `getAllKeys`. `getAllKeys` is a method with a `RCTResponseSenderBlock `. Use `NSLog` to print the contents of the array that is returned in the `RCTResponseSenderBlock`. https://github.com/gpbl/react-native-blur-example/blob/master/node_modules/react-native/React/Modules/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.h#L29

Comment: Sure, just did! Thank you again.

Comment: You are calling `getAllKeys` incorrectly. Please post this as a separate question to avoid messiness. You can paste the link of that question here and I will answer it. Once `getAllKeys` works, you'll have a list of keys, and you can use the appropriate key in `jsonFromLocalRNStrogeForKey:completion`

Comment: Here it`s https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48280006/using-rctasynclocalstorage-getallkeys